# How to replace the indices with the value from another array

Tags: c#

As you can see in following script, after calculation the `results.Add(dotproduct(userseq, z));`, it store the result in a list, sort the list based on the values and show the result index of values before sorting (the original index) and the values like as follow
before sorting:

```
0  0.235
1  0.985
2  0.342
3  0.548
4  0.754
```

After sorting:

```
1  0.985
4  0.754
3  0.548
2  0.342
0  0.235
```

Now, i must replace the sorted index (indices after sorting) to the another value. I have an array (one dimensional) that I must compare the indices of sorted item with that array and if the indices were the same, i read the value of that indices and replace it as indices with is sorted after sorting.
like

```
1  0.985
4  0.754
3  0.548
2  0.342
0  0.235
```

one dimensional Array which the indices are implicit.

```
0  672534
1  234523
2  567808
3  876955
4  89457
```

Finally the result must be like

```
234523  0.985
89457   0.754
876955  0.548
567808  0.342
```

---

```
int sc = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_id.Text);
int n = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_noofrecomm.Text);
//int userseq=Array.IndexOf(d, sc);
for (int yu = 0; yu <= 92161; yu++)
{
    int wer = d[yu];
    if (wer == sc)
    {
        int userseq = yu;
    }
}
var results = new List<float>(1143600);
for (int z = 0; z < 1143600; z++)
{
    results.Add(dotproduct(userseq, z));
}
var sb1 = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var resultwithindex in results.Select((r, index) => new { result = r, Index = index }).OrderByDescending(r => r.result).Take(n))
{
    sb1.AppendFormat("{0}: {1}", resultwithindex.Index, resultwithindex.result);
    sb1.AppendLine();
}
MessageBox.Show(sb1.ToString());
```

Comment: What is going wrong with your code? Can you simplify it to a console application?

Comment: Is list going to be appropriate for the final output? This sounds more of a key value pair! You have a list of values, which you then sort. But those values have a `key` associated with them, which you then want to re-pair. The collection should have values with their keys at all times, instead of `rematching` them later. You should be considering `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` as one of your data structures.

Comment: Thank you @Urda. May you clarify your answer by a comment by an script,please?

Comment: @user3446681 just a moment.

Answer (score 0):

I would store your values as `KeyValuePair` data types

```
// Let's create the list that will store our information
// Keys will be ints, values the doubles
var myList = new List<KeyValuePair<int, double>>();

/*
Here is where you will load the values as you desire
This is up to you! Just add them as KeyValuePair objects to your list
(234523, 0.985), (89457, 0.754), (876955, 0.548), (567808, 0.342)
*/
// For example, I'll just add one:
myList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, double>(567808, 0.342));

// Once you have created your list of desired KeyValuePairs, let's sort them.
// This will sort from high -> low as your example showed
myList.Sort((x, y) => y.Value.CompareTo(x.Value));
```

So then you are left with a sorted list of type `KeyValuePair<int, double>` that you can do with as you please.

... you can learn more about the `KeyValuePair` type [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).